# How to remotely call Gradle to launch new build?

Tags: gradle, remote-server

Is there a way to remotely invoke Gradle from another server.

I saw the tooling API with GradleConnector but I'm wondering how possible I could achieve such remote call.

Else if remote invocation is not supported natively by Gradle
In Daemon mode, is there a way to create a new plugin to act as input with a REST API ? Then it will make Gradle remotely invocable.

Comment: `ssh` is not sufficient?

Comment: I may not have enough access right to use ssh

Comment: SSH is not allow as the user may connect to the secured/protected server where the build is executed and see the build.